# $_POST[string] containing spaces

Tags: php, html, mysql, string, select

On my webpage, I want to be able to select an optio from a dropdown menu. To do that, I select  data from a MySQL-table like this:

```
$quantity_query = "SELECT * FROM input_quantity"; 
$quantity_result = mysqli_query($connection, $quantity_query); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($quantity_result)) {
    $option_quantity .= "<option value = $quantity_name> $quantity_name </option>";
}
```

Then I create the actual dropdown like this:

```
<select id = "new_quantity" name = "new_quantity" style = "width: 100%">
    <?php echo $option_quantity; ?>
</select>
```

Then I want to print `$_POST['new_quantity']` to the screen, which works fine. However, some data I'm using contains spaces, like `100 ml`. In this case, only `100` is printed.

I also tried this

```
$option_quantity .= "<option value = '".$row['quantity']."'>".$row['quantity']."</option>";
```

but that makes no difference.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($quantity_result)) {
    $option_quantity .= "<option value = $quantity_name> $quantity_name </option>";
}
```

to:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($quantity_result)) {
    $option_quantity .= "<option value='$quantity_name'> $quantity_name </option>";
}
```

---

Explanation: when you asign the value to your option, if you don't have the quotes (single/double), the value gets trimmed at the first instance of the space.

---

Example: *test.php*

```
<?php

// Handle Post
if (count($_POST))
{
    var_dump($_POST);
}

// Dummy Options
$option_quantity = '';
for ($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $option_quantity .= "<option value='value$i'>Value $i</option>";
}

?>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<select name="mySelect">
    <?php echo $option_quantity; ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Example Output:

[image]

Comment: Adding the quotes worked! So simple, why didn't I think of that... Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your not creating valid HTML in your loop, I prefer proper `"` vs `'` in HTML properties:

```
$option_quantity = null;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($quantity_result)) {
    $option_quantity .= '<option value="'.$quantity_name.'"> '.$quantity_name.' </option>';
}
```

Also dont forget to create `$option_quantity` before concatenating onto it else your get a Undefined warning if you have error reporting on.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to remove all whitespace:

```
$str = str_replace(' ', '', $row['quantity']);
```

Then use the variable to echo where needed.

EDIT:

Essentially it should look *something* like this.

`$str = str_replace(' ', '', $row['quantity']);
echo '<select id = "new_quantity" name = "new_quantity" style = "width: 100%">';
echo '<option value="' . $str . '">' . $str . '</option></select>';`

Comment: Yep, thats exactly what the OP asked

Comment: Nope, I don't want to remove the spaces. I want to keep the value as they are